# How to i set my GIF visible when i run userform? (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, charts, gif, userform

My chart only updates and shows itself on my running userform, when i click the temp.gif file on my desktop. How do i get it to automatically show itself when i run the code?

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")

'ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.Activate

 Set CurrentChart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart


    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"

    Image1.Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)

 End Sub
```

Sincerly,

Peyko.

Comment: Have you had a chance to review the answer below? If it is working for you, please mark as accepted. If not, let me know what's wrong and I can help revise it.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, nothing happens to the `Image1`.  I was not able to get the image to show until I added some more code, try this:

```
Private Sub Image1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet")

'ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart.Activate

 Set CurrentChart = ws.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart


    Fname = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
    CurrentChart.Export Filename:=Fname, FilterName:="GIF"

    With Image1
        .Picture = LoadPicture(Fname)
        .PictureSizeMode = 1 'Stretch
        .PictureAlignment = 2 'Center
        .PictureTiling = False
        .SpecialEffect = 2 'Sunken
    End With

 End Sub
```