# Load chart as image giving Runtime-error 481: Invalid picture

Tags: excel, vba

Here, I want to reflect the charts from Excel sheet to userform Image. However, I have getting an error like 'Invalid Picture". Please assist.

```vb
Dim CurrentChart As Chart
Dim FName As String

FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"
Set CurrentChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart
CurrentChart.Export Filename:=FName, filtername:="GIF"
Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22663531/11683?

Comment: I am still getting same error

Answer (score 0):

Try activating the chart before the the `.Export`

`ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate`

Full code below:

```
Dim CurrentChart As Chart
Dim FName As String

FName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.gif"

Set CurrentChart = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Chart

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate

CurrentChart.Export Filename:=FName, filtername:="GIF"

Image2.Picture = LoadPicture(FName)
```